# Display "Post 2 of 4" on single post page?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, pagination, pages, single

I have a custom post type called Projects.

When viewing a single 'project' post I have next/prev buttons to navigate through them.

I also want to display text saying "Project 2 of 4" or ideally pagination icons.

This is easy on index.php but I can't work out how to do this on a single post page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [create a new query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for all posts in your custom post type, then iterate through each and match it to the current post id to figure out its position.

```
// save current id to match later
$current_project_id = $post->ID;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'project',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$all_projects = new WP_Query( $args );

while( $all_projects->have_posts() ) : $all_projects->the_post();

    // simple 'if' test to find the current post in the loop
    // note that current_post starts at zero, which is why we add 1 to it.
    // you can also output the_title, the_permalink, thumbnails, etc..

    if( $post->ID == $current_project_id ):
        echo "project " . ( $all_projects->current_post + 1 ) . " of " . $all_projects->post_count;
    endif;

endwhile;
```

The caveat here is that you're loading all of your projects on every page, which could get expensive if you've got a lot of projects. You'll probably want to set up some caching to keep things speedy anyway.

Comment: thanks milo - i'll give this a go. And how about if i wanted to use pagination buttons like this - http://design.sparklette.net/teaches/how-to-add-wordpress-pagination-without-a-plugin/#

Comment: you would get the links to each post via `the_permalink()`, and the numbers for each button from `$all_projects->current_post`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was EXACTLY what I was looking for!

Comment: Hi Milo, I've just found this is causing a problem displaying the_content();  On my local test server it displays the content from the first post on all posts, and on my web server it doesn't display the content at all. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I put my code in a new question here - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30841/wp-query-causing-problems-with-the-content