# Wp-query causing problems with the_content();

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, the-content

I'm using some code provided [in an answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30587/display-post-2-of-4-on-single-post-page/30594#30594) on here to calculate "post X of Y" and display pagination icons on single.php.

It works beautifully but it's causing problems displaying `the_content();`

On my local MAMP server it displays the content from the first post on every post, and on my web server it doesn't display the content at all.

---

My full code is below:

```
<div class="project-pagination">

    <?php

    // save current id to match later
    $current_project_id = $post->ID;

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'portfolio',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    $all_projects = new WP_Query( $args );

    ?>

    <ul>

    <?php

    while( $all_projects->have_posts() ) : $all_projects->the_post();

        // simple 'if' test to find the current post in the loop
        // note that current_post starts at zero, which is why we add 1 to it.
        // you can also output the_title, the_permalink, thumbnails, etc..

        $permalink = get_permalink();
        $projectnum = $all_projects->current_post+1;

        if( $post->ID == $current_project_id ){
            echo "<li class='project-page-btn-current'></li>";
        }else {
            echo "<li><a class='project-page-btn' href='".$permalink."'></a></li>";
        }

    endwhile;

    ?>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `wp_reset_postdata();` after the `endwhile;` statement.

Comment: Q is where the pagination is implemented. Also the query itself, as it calls the class into the var _shouldn't_ cause problems.